# Dealing with tag overlap for 'ranking'

Tags: discussion, tags

Consider that we have the following topics:

- Page Rank (Google's trademarked rank indicator)
- Alexa Ranking
- Over-all ranking (in general, not specific to any service or SE)

This would mean three very similar tags:

[google-page-rank], [alexa-rank], [site-ranking]

And I'm sure that people would naturally use all three, almost all of the time when asking any question that has to do with ranking.

Should we have tags for each type of rank, or just one meta 'ranking' tag?

Comment: please don't use the `<kbd>` style to make "tags". It is a personal pet peeve of mine, to the point that I will block the style from the site if this happens.

Comment: @Jeff - There are a lot of decaffeinated brands on the market that are just as tasty as the real thing. Since its highly unlikely that we'll be sharing keyboard shortcuts here, its probably better to just nuke the style. I do remember how they were abused on SO meta, that wasn't my intent.

Answer (score 3):

Since "PageRank" is an official term for Google's algorithm, I see no reason to specify "google" in the tag. Other search engines obviously use a similar system but they don't call it "PageRank" and they don't publish any numbers or anything.

I'd suggest using these tags:

- **pagerank** (all one word)
- **alexa-rank** (I don't expect this to be particularly popular)
- **ranking** (or maybe **serps-ranking**) for questions about a page's actual position in SERPs.

Comment: I think `serps-ranking` is a good umbrella for all of it, actually .. and just make the others synonyms

Answer (score 1):

What does Alexa ranking have to do with Google's page rank or "site-ranking"? I'd suggest "google-page-rank" for the first tag though, just in case Google goes belly up.

Comment: That's pretty much my point, the tags are related but describe something different. So I'm wondering if one generic 'ranking' tag would be better than several (or more) tags describing a specific kind of rank. There are more beyond what I put in the example, as well.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, my $.02... The issue here is that there are two completely different types of rankings and [site-rankning] is ambiguous as to which one is being referred to.

For questions about **ranking in search engines** I would vote for using [seo-ranking], [site-ranking] is probably a synonym (as this is *usually* what people mean by it) and [page-rank] and [google-page-rank] are definitely synonyms.

Alexa rankings are about **traffic to the site** relative to other sites and would be better described by [traffic-ranking] (or something similar) which would cover other ways of ranking sites by the amount of traffic they get. [alexa-ranking] would by a synonym.

Comment: Isn't Alexa Rating dependent on traffic by people running one of the amazon/A3/Alexa toolbars?

Comment: @Noctrine, that's correct and more or less my point.