# Should "ranking", "page-ranking", and "site-ranking" be tag synonyms

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

We have these tags which to me all mean about the same thing:

- [ranking](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ranking) - 26
- [site-ranking](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/site-ranking) - 73
- [page-ranking](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/page-ranking) - 44

[There was some discussion around some of these tags a few years ago](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55/dealing-with-tag-overlap-for-ranking) with some votes for [serps-ranking](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/serps-ranking) as a good canonical name for [ranking](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ranking) (although there are no questions tagged with "serps-ranking" at all).

We also have these tags which I would leave separate:

- [pagerank](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pagerank) - Google algorithm for assigning link value to sites
- [google-ranking](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-ranking) - Ranking as applied specificially to the Google search engine

Answer (score 1):

The three of those should be merged although I don't know if I like `serp-ranking` for a tag name. Mainly because I don't like the word `serp`. Perhaps a more descriptive name like `search-engine-ranking`? Or do we unite them under `page-ranking` since that is technically correct and also allows us to distinguish between that concept and `pagerank` which is helpful when suggested tags are presented.

Comment: I agree that serp-ranking isn't ideal.  SERP isn't a widely enough known acronym for that.    If we went with page-ranking, I think it would increase confusion rather than decrease confusion.

Comment: Would you say `search-engine-ranking` would be the next best alternative? Or do you have another suggestion?

Comment: "search-engine-ranking" would be fine, and so would just plain "ranking", in my opinion.

Comment: Wouldn't just `rankings` be good enough on its own since it could be paired with the likes of other tags like `Google`.

Comment: damn you, beat me too it :P

Comment: If I were to go ahead with this now, I would merge [tag:page-ranking] and [tag:site-ranking] into [tag:ranking].  I want to make sure that is what we are talking about here before I proceed.  Bybe's comment has an "s" on "rankings" which I wouldn't include.

Comment: Works for me...